# How can I add fake erosion in my infinite terrain generation?

Tags: algorithm, procedural-generation

I'm making a game where the terrain is infinite and procedurally generated. I'm using Perlin noise with octaves to make the terrain shape. I would like to implement some sort of erosion to make the terrain looks more realistic. However, all the articles I found on the Internet present erosion simulations that work with a fixed-size terrain, and these simulations seems to be taking a lot of time to compute. I tried to search for faster algorithms that work with infinite terrain, but all I found was some Reddit posts which did not really help me, and some blog posts with no explanation of how the algorithm works. So, my question is: How can I make a fake erosion algorithm that is fast and works with infinite terrain generation ?

Comment: You could generate it in blocks of 3x3 chunks, then interpolate in the overlapping regions. That way it will look smooth but you don't need to pre-compute a infinite amount of terrain at once. It will still be slow though

Comment: [There was a good Twitter thread recently about the problem of generating drainage basins and rivers with noise](https://twitter.com/lorenschmidt/status/1584636655444848640). [I also saw an interesting paper about this problem](https://github.com/mgaillard/Noise).

Comment: Thanks for your answers @mousetail and @dmgregory! The github paper sounds interesting, I'll look into it!